# Which common LaTeX Fonts come prepackaged with specific settings for Microtype?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, microtype, kerning, protrusion

For anyone interested in achieving the very best microtypography: Some fonts apparently come with `microtype` specific settings while other fonts don't. In that case `microtype` applies "Default" settings that might be less than perfect for all those other fonts.

There are a good many fonts available with LaTeX, so it might be difficult to figure out all the ones that have specific `microtype` settings, but we can note some of the most popular ones.  Currently, I'm using the `newcent` font families and wonder if `microtype` is using it's default microtypography settings, which I never tweak.

Which of the common fonts have specific configuration settings for use with the `microtype` package?

(Please add to this list of popular fonts as more font `microtype` configurations become available for them, or make a note besides the ones that don't support custom configurations, or have shown poor performance)

1. I believe all the major TeX distributions come with this PSNFSS collection of PostScript fonts.  Do these have prepackaged settings?

- `package` — / Roman Family / Sans Serif / Typewriter /
- default — / CM Roman / CM Sans Serif / CM Typewriter /
- `mathpazo` — / Palatino / none / none /
- `mathptmx` — / Times / none / none /
- `helvet` — / none / Helvetica / none /
- `avant` — / none / Avant Garde / none
- `chancery` — / Zaph Chancery / none / none /
- `bookman` — / Bookman / Avant Garde / Courier /
- `newcent` — / New Century Schoolbook / Avant Garde / Courier /
- `charter` — / Charter / none / none /

2. Also I use LyX to organize my novel, and these are the other Roman fonts that are available from it's drop down menu:

- Latin Modern
- Utopia** (`fourier`)
- Bitstream Charter
- Bera Serif
- Concrete Roman

3. Here are some more popular fonts. (Garamond is the most popular for novels today):

- URW Garamond
- EB Garamond
- Garamond Expert
- Linux Libertine
- Lucida Bright

Since my project is a novel, I'd like to chose a font from among those that have `microtype` specific settings.

Comment: Look in `texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/`.  EB Garamond has a configuration file too.

Comment: Great! I adjusted the list above adding EB Garamond.

Comment: @Thérèse That's a good start. But it is a bit more complex. It isn't just a matter of which font, but also which engine and which encoding you're using. To complicate things further, lack of a specific file is not necessarily an issue if an appropriate alias is configured and the font aliased is sufficiently similar. Some of this information is not in that directory. Moreover, font packages may have configuration files which are located somewhere else. But this comment will get too long...;)

Comment: The `microtype` documentation lists all fonts, including aliases, for which the package provides dedicated settings (table 3 on page 21). But that's only the ones shipped with `microtype` itself, there are other packages that contain their own settings (see @cfr's answer).

Comment: In order to fit the Q&A-format here better, I’d suggest separating your list off into an answer (a community wiki answer, if you’d like other users to edit and complement the list).

Comment: Those are the fonts I was asking about specifically. Not all have custom configuration files.  For example, I now know that New Century Schoolbook does not, but Palatino and Charter do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think it is reasonable to expect a full list to be created and maintained here. I think it is better to explain how to figure out whether fonts have this support so that users can determine the current answer for a specific font for themselves. If nothing else, this will enable people to check whether an answer here is still correct.

Thérèse is right that `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFDIST)/tex/latex/microtype/` contains configuration files for `microtype`. But this provides only a limited amount of information because:

- some configuration files are located elsewhere;
- the presence of a configuration file does not establish support in general because whether a particular font has such support depends on further factors (the engine, the encoding etc.);
- the lack of a configuration file does not demonstrate the absence of such support because one font may be declared as an alias and, if the fonts are sufficiently similar, this may amount to a custom configuration.

I illustrate these points by examples.

### Configuration files elsewhere

- EB Garamond: `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFDIST)/tex/latex/ebgaramond/mt-EBGaramond.cfg`.
- Junicode: `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFDIST)/tex/latex/junicode/mt-Junicode.cfg`

### Presence of file does not establish support

A file may be present without supporting a font in a particular encoding with a particular engine.

- Some features of `microtype` just are not supported by some engines regardless of configuration files. All features are supported by pdfTeX, many are now supported by LuaTeX, some are supported by XeTeX and none are supported by TeX.
- `mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg` does not support Latin Modern if you compile with pdfTeX because this file concerns encodings only used by XeTeX and LuaTeX. So the presence of a file for a font does not establish that customised settings will be used in your document, even if your engine supports all `microtype` features and you use that font. [Latin Modern is supported - see below - but this file proves nothing if you are using pdfTeX.]

### Absence of file does not establish lack of support

- One file may support more than one font.

`mt-cmr.cfg` includes this code:

```
\SetProtrusion
   [ name     = lmr-T1,
     load     = cmr-T1   ]
   { encoding = {T1,LY1},
     family   = lmr      }
   {
     \textquotedblleft  = {300,400},  \textquotedblright = {300,400}
   }
```

This means that Latin Modern Roman will largely use the protrusion settings for Computer Modern Roman when loaded in encodings `T1` or `LY1`, with a couple of additions or adjustments.

But the crucial work is done in `microtype.cfg`. There a good number of *aliases* are defined, including:

```
\ifMT@fontspec
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmr} {Latin Modern Roman}
\else
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmr} {cmr}  % lmodern
\fi
```

This means that if `fontspec` is in use, the settings from `mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg` will be used. Otherwise, the settings for Computer Modern Roman will be used.

However, this is not necessarily true merely because you are using Latin Modern Roman. You must be using it *as* `lmr`. If you are using the `lmodern` package, all will be well. But if you are using `cfr-lm`, then you are using Latin Modern Roman but you are *not* using `lmr`:

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{clm\cfrlm@rmpt\cfrlm@rmol}
```

Which family this is depends on the options used, but whatever options are active, the result will not be `lmr`. It will be `clm...`. So the alias configured in `microtype.cfg` will have no effect.

To figure out whether `microtype` will use custom settings, we need to look to another section of `cfr-lm.sty` (with some comments removed):

```
\newcommand{\cfr@ffs}{% alias to cmr
  clm,clm2,clm2j,clmj,% roman
  clms,clm2js,clm2s,clmjs,% sans
  clmqs,clm2jqs,clm2qs,clmjqs%
  }
\gdef\cfrlm@MicroType@Aliases{%
  \@for \xx:=\cfr@ffs \do {%
          \DeclareMicrotypeAlias{\xx}{cmr}}%
  }
\def\cfrlm@MT@Hook{\cfrlm@MicroType@Aliases}
\@ifpackageloaded{microtype}{%
  \cfrlm@MT@Hook}{%
  \@ifundefined{Microtype@Hook}{%
        \let\Microtype@Hook\cfrlm@MT@Hook}{%
        \g@addto@macro\Microtype@Hook{\cfrlm@MT@Hook}}}
```

This sets up aliases for the various families to Computer Modern Roman if, and only if, `microtype` is loaded by the user.

[To be honest, I'm not certain these are right now. Every time I look into this, it seems different. However, my code is apparently based on discussion on this site, so it must be good ;), mustn't it?]

## The Acid Test

If all of that seems really complicated, that's because it is. Fortunately, there is a very simple way to determine whether a font has customised `microtype` settings or not. Simply use the font in a document, compile with `microtype` and examine the log file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{microtype,kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

Compiling this test with pdfLaTeX, the following lines appear in the log file:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman
```

This shows that the alias has resulted in the relevant settings being loaded.

Now replace `cfr-lm` by `kpfonts` and examine the log:

```
Package microtype Info: Loading generic settings for font family
(microtype)             `jkp' (encoding: OT1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
```

This tells us that no custom settings for `jkp` with encoding `OT1` were found and that `microtype` is therefore relying on generic settings in this case.

### Final note

Of course, whether font-specific settings are an improvement depends entirely on the quality of those settings. If I've messed up the aliases in `cfr-lm` or the person who created the settings for Computer Modern Roman lacked an eye for detail, you might be better off with the generics!

## EDIT

Here are the results replacing `cfr-lm` in the above with `newcent` and compiling with pdfLaTeX:

```
Package microtype Info: Loading generic settings for font family
(microtype)             `pnc' (encoding: OT1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
```

So `microtype` uses generic settings in this case.

Comment: Nice answer! You could add the [MinionPro](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minionpro) package, which also provides `microtype` settings.

Comment: @Robert Thanks! I don't see much to be gained by adding `MinionPro`, especially since it does not support current versions of the fonts. My whole answer is aimed at teaching the reader to make their *own* tofu... :-). In any case, LaTeX certainly does not come with Minion Pro, and the question is focused on fonts which come with 'LaTeX'. But, as it happens, the hook code in `cfr-lm.sty` is based on that used in `MinionPro`.

Comment: Right, just wanted to mention it as it was the first package to provide its own settings (and for which that hook was actually introduced).

Comment: @Robert Ah. I didn't know that. Interesting. It is a useful hook!

Comment: and New Century Schoolbook {newcent} is included in the major TeX Distributions. It's an important font: The Supreme Court is required to use a "Century" font in all their briefings.  My output does look a little BLOCKY, but it's perfectly justified with fewer hypenations and several other fonts I tested.  Can you explain part of my logfile about newcent:
" LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 56.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+pnc on input line 56.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pnc.fd
File: t1pnc.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/pnc.
) "

Comment: @user12711 I wouldn't go by court requirements. There are jurisdictions where everything has to be submitted in Courier! Anyway, what do you want to know about that excerpt from the log file? First it tells you what it is trying to do: load font settings for fonts in encoding `T1` and family `pnc`. This is due to some instruction on input line 56. Then it notes that it has found `t1pnc.fd` and where, and confirms that this file provides settings for encoding `T1` and family `pnc`.

Comment: @user12711 Presumably you also loaded `fontenc` with option `T1`. So it loads the font in that encoding for you. I didn't change to `T1`, so it used `OT1` when I tested. The only difference in output, as far as `microtype`'s warning is concerned, is the `OT1` in the message I posted is `T1` if I load `fontenc` with option `T1`. That's because `microtype` looks for settings by font family and font encoding. So if `OT1` is active, it looks for them for `OT1/pnc`. If `T1` is active, it looks for settings for `T1/pnc`.

Comment: @user12711 `T1` and `OT1` are font encodings. `pnc` is the name of the font family in what is called the Karl Berry scheme. (Such names are doled out, when necessary, by Karl Berry who is responsible for many things TeX. If you want such a name, you email him and ask for it.) Anyway, the first letter is the foundry (`p` means Adobe). The next 2 letters are the family name (`nc` presumably for New Century). I think that's it. Did I miss anything?

Comment: that's a great explanation for a complex issue.  BTW, I was using LyX and picked New Century Schoolbook for Roman Font from the Dropdown Menu. (It impressed me that Century was a requirement) and I had read that it was developed for readability in textbooks

Comment: @user12711 Yes. It is nice. Even if it uses default `microtype` settings. What are you going to use now? I think it is weird that not only is Courier required but that when people try to change it, other people protest. (I could understand just not getting around to getting the rule changed - life is short. But actively protesting in its favour?!)

Comment: @user12711 You might also like `tgschola`.

Comment: That looks really nice, an expanded New Century Schoolbook version. Do you know if it has a microtype configuration file? I might still stick with newcent, but I'm strongly considering Palatino, Bookman, Garamondx (or download EB Garamond) It seems everyone is using a Garamond for novels.  I did manage to get Garamondx downloaded and installed from a getnonfreefonts command, but I'm not sure how I'd do that with tgschola.  Would I use my TeXLive package manager or manual (I'm using Kubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @user12711 I don't think so. You could always test. EB Garamond and the TeX-Gyre fonts are part of TeX Live. I don't know how your distro packages them. I have always used vanilla TL, which includes the lot. You might have to install additional packages if you've not got a full installation of TeX. (Vanilla TL is easier IMHO, even though you have to learn to install it.)

Comment: @cfr I'm experimenting, making my own mt-pnc.cfg file to put into my microtype package folder.  I discovered the shapes are very much like [bch] Charter except bolder and larger.  The first thing I've done is take the mt-bch.cfg file and replaced all references of bch with pnc.  I just want to see if it will work, then can tweak the protrusion settings later.  All I need to do is put that file in the folder with Microtype's other cfg file and pdflatex and microtype will use it with pnc [newcent, i.e. new century schoolbook]?  So far. So far.  n.c.schoolbook, Charter and Palatino are favorites.

Comment: @user12711 Don't put it into your main distribution tree. Install either into your local tree or into your personal tree. Otherwise, things get messy (and may disappear). That *may* be all you need to do. It depends on how you are using the font. Specifically, it matters whether the family name matches. If not, you will need to declare an alias..

Answer (score 0):

Related: What if you wish to use a particular font, but it does not have existing protrusion settings? Is there a strategy? Yes, if you are willing to do the work. This is best for OpenType fonts; results with other types are unknown (to me).

You can load the font file into a font editor, such as FontForge. Take note of its grid units (almost always 1000 per em, for OpenType *.otf fonts). Copy an important letter such as lowercase `i` to to Guide layer. This will be a reference for position.

Then look at each glyph that is of interest to you (depends on your language). How much do you need to move it horizontally, so that its left side looks good when compared to the Guide `i` ? That is a useful value for left protrusion.

Right protrusion is trickier, since it involves comparing the right side of the reference letter, to the right side of other letters. A single Guide letter will not work. But, you can create a copy font with everything flipped horizontally; then its left-side values will be the right-side values for the original font.

When writing the microtype protrusion values, be sure to use units of em.

Caution: Use your judgement. Some folks recommend protrusions that were used long ago (pre-automobile) but are not generally used nowadays. For example, hanging a hyphen outside the normal textblock.